# How can I change the keys of an unsorted array to what they would be if the array was sorted?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I sort an array by value, but instead of changing the position of the values, change the position of the keys?

```
Array
(
    [0] => 16
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 30
)
```

When I sort this array, I  want to  get the output like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 16
    [0] => 12
    [2] => 30
)
```

Comment: how is this sorting by value? Neither the keys are sorted nor the value

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Check out the [guidelines for asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)- we'd love it if you can restructure the title of this, and format your code/pseudocode snippets.

Comment: I think I understood what you were asking, and I edited your question to try to help clarify it. If I was mistaken, feel free to **[edit]** it again to make corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your starting array:

```
$a = [16, 12, 30];
```

First make a copy:

```
$b = $a;
```

Then use [`asort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) on one of them to sort it while maintaining the key association:

```
asort($a);
```

Then use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) with [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to create your result array using the the keys from the sorted array, and the values from the unsorted array.

```
$result = array_combine(array_keys($a), $b);
```